# Selecting rows in MUI DataGrid programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to select the next row when a button on the screen is pressed

I tried with using id values, but this fails when different sorting rules are applied to the grid

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This post doesn't really have enough detail for anyone here to help you, though.  Can you update it to provide more details, including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the problem you are having, as well as what you've already tried?  We will definitely need to see code, including your JS, HTML, and probably CSS, before anyone here can help you with a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.